# pasar datos a un json desde una función con javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, funcion

Hola estoy intentando obtener información mediante `AJAX` con una función para usarla en otras, pero me da problemas porque se ejecuta el `onload` luego de que se ha ejecutado la función a la que quiero pasar los resultados o sea se ejecuta `ajax()` y envia la peticón pero no se ejecuta el onload sino hasta despues de que se ha ejecutado `getImages()`. Les dejo parte del código.

```
   response = {};
function ajax() {
  var xhr, formData, media, resp = [];
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.withCredentials = false;
  xhr.open('POST', 'interface.php');
  xhr.onload = function(){
    var json;
    if (xhr.status != 200){
      failure('HTTP Error:' + xhr.status);
      return;
    }
    json = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
    if(!json){
      console.log('Invalid JSON:' + xhr.responseText);
      return;
    }
     response['data'] = json || false;
  }
  formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('action', 'getmedia');
  formData.append('media', media);
  xhr.send(formData);
  data = xhr.data;
}
var getImages = function (data) {
    var img = data.img, vid = data.vid, aud = data.aud, doc = data.doc, rar = data.rar, apk = data.apk;
    var imgs = document.getElementById('media-img'),
        vids = document.getElementById('media-vid'),
        auds = document.getElementById('media-aud'),
        docs = document.getElementById('media-doc'),
        rars = document.getElementById('media-rar'),
        apks = document.getElementById('media-apk');
    if (!!img) {
      imgs.innerHTML = img;
    } else if (!!vid) {
      vids.innerHTML = vid;
    }else if (!!aud) {
      auds.innerHTML = aud;
    }else if (!!doc) {
      docs.innerHTML = doc;
    }else if (!!rar) {
      rars.innerHTML = rar;
    }else if (!!apk) {
      apks.innerHTML = apk;
    }
  };
  ajax();
  getImages(response.data);
```

Comment: listo , solo debía declarar la función y ejecutarla antes del bloque de código donde se definen el resto de las funciones.

Comment: Lo siento, no entiendo el comentario ni lo que has hecho para hacerlo funcionar bien. Si has encontrado otra respuesta distinta a la mia que te funciona para solucionar tu pregunta deberias ponerla como respuesta completa para que la comunidad lo sepa y colabores con el sitio. Al cabo de x horas podrás marcala como aceptada y así los que consulten la pregunta encontrarán la solución que funciona más facilmente y la pregunta no quedara eternamente pendiente.

Comment: es que yo las ejecutaba juntas dentro de un una serie de condicionales `if` y `for of`, lo que hice fue ejecutar ajax  fuera de los condicionales y así `response.data` siempre esatará disponible y con los datos actualizados.

Comment: Vale, pero eso que dices es en un código aparte de este, vamos, que no estaba en la pregunta. Bueno, sea como sea lo has solucionado, perfecto. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Debes colocar la llamada a la función `getImages()` dentro del `xhr.onload` si quieres que se ejecuten en ese orden.

Por lo tanto donde pone esto:

```
response['data'] = json || false;
```

le pones esto:

```
response['data'] = json || false;
getImages(response.data);
```

y lo borras o comentas de la llamada que le haces despues del `ajax()`.

Ya nos dirás si te ha funcionado.

Comment: si asi lo tengo funcionando, la cuestion es que quiero almacenar la respuesta en el json para poder usarlas luego en otras funciones que no han de ejecutarse en el mismo momento y no encuentro la manera de retornar los resultados desde el `onload` del `XHR`, si me pudieran dar recomendaciónes de como hacerlo funcionar, o explicarme porqué el bloque de codigo se ejecuta luego de terminar la ejecución de la función

Comment: No se si te refieres a crear variables globales fuera de las funciones para luego asignarlas dentro del onload, y volverlas a utilizar despues, o bien si quieres incluir dentro del response.data el resultado del getImages... sea como sea creo que todo pasa o bien por asignar variables globales (o una tipo array u objeto) que se asigne dentro del onload, o bien usar un `return` en alguna parte para lo mismo, es decir, asignarlo a una variable global para usarse despues en otra parte, o bien llamar a la función desde otra función para seguir teniendo el scope bien.No acabo de entenderlo, sorry

Comment: es que no logro ninguna de las dos o retornar o almacenar, pero realmente quiero almacenarla en una variable global, que me sugieres.

Comment: No se si te refieres a esto: `var varGlobal=ajax();` donde al final de la función ajax() le pones un `return data` que será guardado en la variable `varGlobal` que ya usaras despues en otra parte en lugar del `ajax()` a secas que pones ahi... es eso lo que buscas?

Comment: si así lo quería pero por más que lo intentaba me retorna ba siempre `null` o `undefined`

Comment: Bueno, a ver si me se explicar... cuando realizas una peticion XMLHttpRequest estás lanzando una petición AJAX asíncrona, que quiere decir que el navegador la ejecutará cuando pueda, pero todo lo que no esté dentro de esa función se ejecutará sin esperar su resultado. Por eso mi respuesta es adecuada para que se ejecute tu función getImages() correctamente. Pero si lo que pretendes es devolver un valor de una llamada asincrona a un código que está fuera del ambito de la petición XMLHttpRequest simplemente no te va a funcionar porque no espera a que este termine.

Comment: Y aunque pudieras devolver una variable, que he probado y se puede, ésta no te funcionará tampoco (eso es curioso porque para un **console.log** si que me funciona, pero para pasarla como parámetro de algo no).  Para que lo puedas probar puedes sacar el `var json` de la función del **onload** para hacerlo global. Luego, al final de la función `ajax()`, puedes devolverlo con un `return json` y luego recogerlo fuera con un `var varGlobal=ajax();` y hacerle un `console.log(varGlobal)`... pero si intentas pasarselo a getImages fuera del `ajax()` no te funcionará.